# Hiding navigation nodes in WSS dynamically

Tags: navigation, wss-3.0

The SPNavigation property IsVisible only returns true. I have seen a lot of posts on the net stating the same thing. I know there is a way of hiding the nodes in MOSS using the PublishingWeb class, the problem I have is that we are using WSS which does not have microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.dll.

Is there a way of hiding navigation nodes in WSS dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Not without writing your own sitemapprovider.  I once tried setting the same properties using a WSS site that MOSS uses in it's navigation, including BlankUrl (header) and Target (open in a new window) but they didn't work because the wss sitemapprovider doesn't pass those properties when it converts the node from a SPNavigationNode to a SiteMapNode.  I ended up writing my own sitemapprovider that reads the spnavigationnodecollection and passes the properties through.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
protected SiteMapNode SPNavigationNodeToSiteMapNode(SPNavigationNode spNode, SPWeb web)
{
    if (spNode == null) return null;

    SiteMapNode node = NewSiteMapNode("sid:" + spNode.Id.ToString(),
              spNode.Url,
              spNode.Title,
              web.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower());
    if (spNode.Id == ROOT_ID ||
     spNode.Id == ALT_ROOT_ID)
    {
     node.Url = "sid:" + spNode.Id.ToString();
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)spNode.Properties["BlankUrl"]))
    {
     node.Url = string.Empty;
    }

    foreach (object key in spNode.Properties.Keys)
    {
     switch (key.ToString())
     {
      case "Title": break;
      case "ID": break;
      case "ToolTip": break;
      case "Expanded": break;
      case "NavigateUrl": break;
      default:
       node[key.ToString()] = spNode.Properties[key].ToString();
       break;
     }
    }

    return node;
}
```